# Problem import deck.gl with react and Vite

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl

I am getting the error

```
'/node_modules/.vite/deps/@deck__gl_layers.js?v=da5738d0' does not provide an export named 'DeckGL'
```

despite it being listed as a dependency in my package.json, and in node_modules

```
"name": "airbnbclone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "airbnbclone",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.11.7",
        "@react-oauth/google": "^0.6.1",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "deck.gl": "^8.8.23",
        "firebase": "^9.17.1",
        "firestore": "^1.1.6",
        "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
        "material-ui-popup-state": "^5.0.4",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.43.0",
        "react-leaflet": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
      }
    },
```

I am trying to import deck.gl like this

```
import { DeckGL, GlobeView } from "@deck.gl/layers";
import { MapView } from "@deck.gl/core";
```

To no avail, it for some reason isn't registering these imports.